# access to single pixel of SuperpixelSlic object Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, superpixels

i've this code where im applying the algorithm slic superpixel on a image. Then after showing my image with a imageview,the user should select with touch the superpixels he wants to select.My problem is how can i access to a single superpixel so i can color it to point out? 
Now,what i've done is this:

Here i applied the superpixelslic algorithm to my image and i show it

```
    newMat=new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(image,newMat,true);
    SuperpixelSLIC x= Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC(newMat, Ximgproc.SLIC,rows/9,(float)25);
    x.iterate(num_iterations);
    if (min_element_size>0)
        x.enforceLabelConnectivity(min_element_size);
    Mat mask=new Mat();
    x.getLabelContourMask(mask,true);
    newMat.setTo( new Scalar(0,0,255),mask);
    Utils.matToBitmap(newMat,image);
    Mat labels=new Mat();
    x.getLabels(labels);
```